# SQLite Studio app on Ubuntu 22.04 gives status 'Could not check for updates (SSL handshake failed)'

Tags: ssl

I am new to Ubuntu. I have just downloaded SQLite Studio on Ubuntu 22.04 and opened it. Just when I opened it another small window appeared asking me for something. I didn't read it carefully and just closed the app completely. Now every time I open the app it shows me Status 'Could not check for updates (SSL handshake failed)'. I thought if I remove the app from the download folder and redownload it, it will disappear but the same status message still appears after opening the app. I asked the maintainer of the app in GitHub and he explained the following:

"it looks somewhat similar to what you can encounter under Windows too. I mean it looks like Ubuntu firewall asked you whether you agree to allow the SQLiteStudio app to reach out to the internet (to check for updates), or not. Since you did not acknowledge it, it defaulted to "no" and it is this way till now.

I'm not 100% sure that this is the reason, just guessing. "

Could someone help me please to get rid of this status message so I don't see it every time I open the app? Thank you.

Comment: "The Ubuntu firewall"? That could refer to `ufw` or `iptables`. List the firewall rules for each of these with `sudo ufw show raw` and `sudo iptables -L` and see if any of these point to the GitHub server.

Comment: Hi Jos, thank you for your reply. Not sure why it should point to the GitHub server. The issue has nothing to do with GitHub server. The issue is that it is the status message that pops up every time I open SQLite Studio. The maintainer of SQLite Studio advise me to check with 'askubuntu.com' and perhaps here someone knows the answer how to get rid of this status message.

Comment: By "checking for updates" I thought you meant "connect to the GitHub server". Of course, it could be any server instead. This maintainer believes that your answering "no" has created a firewall rule, so I explained how to verify that, so you can remove that rule.

Comment: ok, understood. Sorry, if my explanation was misleading. Above commands do not show any points to SQLite Studio server.

Comment: In that case, SQLStudio must have stored your decision somewhere else. I'd look in `~/.config` if there is a `SQLStudio` (or similar) subdirectory.

Comment: On Linux SQLiteStudio is downloaded as a portable app and is not installed like usual apps on Ubuntu. I downloaded a zipfile from SQLiteStudio, unzipped it and then inside the unzipped file there is SQLiteStudio executable file. To run the app I click on that file.   You are right SQLiteStudio stored my decision somewhere but it is not in  ~/.config...

Comment: Yes it is. The configuration is in `.config/SalSoft/SQLiteStudio/settings3` which is in itself a SQLite3 database. I suppose you could delete that and start again.

Comment: Your answer helped to restart the app with the installation wizard. Thank you.